# div scroll not working as expected

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

So I'm working on a layout like this:

```
<body>
<div id="master">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>TEST 1</li>
            <li>TEST 2</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="content">
            <div>
                <p>EXAMPLE TITLE</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p>EXAMPLE DESCRIPTION</p>
            </div>
            <div id="list">
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <p>TEST</p>
                    </li>

                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see, I have a title, description and then a list of elements. Scrolling this list you notice that the last elements cannot be reach. Just a couple of them, similar to the amount of space that both title and description are taking.

How can I fix this? Notice that I do not want to use fixed height, otherwise that will be fixed quickly. I want this to be responsive so that's why I'm using height: 100%. I'm not always sure about the size or amount of text for both title and descriptions.

Check this fiddle with all the elements and css
http://jsfiddle.net/jWtQL/23/

Comment: Are you normalizing your CSS? http://jsfiddle.net/jWtQL/26/

Comment: No, and I have no idea what was that, thanks! So I guess this would better then resetting browser styles right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to add too many things here, the very first is you need to reset the default browser styles. As you commented that you were not aware of that, use [CSS Reset Stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or if you are looking to focus the general ones, using the snippet below will suffice

```
* {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
```

Secondly, you are using `height: 100%;` for the `#content` but you have the text above it, also using properties like `border` and `padding` add up to these, so your element will overflow the viewport and as you are using `overflow: hidden;` on `html, body` you won't be able to see the text.

**So, what's the solution?**

Use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) here

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jWtQL/32/)

```
#content {
    display: block;
    height: calc(100% - 50px); /* 50px approx of the content above 
                                  overflowed element */
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

---

Would also like to point out that when you are making responsive websites, do use the below snippet to alter the default box model, which will force the elements to count the `border` and `padding` inside the element rather than counting outside.

```
* {
   /* First two properties are for resets */
   margin: 0; 
   padding: 0;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I just can't find any cross browser solution for calc() since I need to support ie7+ :/

Comment: @nhenrique use jquery with `.resize()` as well as `onready` will do the similar thing for you

Comment: I'm going to try that! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

this is what you have to do:

```
#content {
    display: block;
    height: 70%; /* Change the height which is less than the parent div */
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
```

**[fidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/jWtQL/39/)**

Comment: thanks, this one also works. I just have to play around with the media queries now :)